# How can I do to save the param selected?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I did a form to save parameters using 3 options

```
- ABC
- DEF
- OTHER
```

When I select ABC will save id=1

When I select DEF WILL save id=2

But when I select OTHER the javascript trick will show other select box with options

```
- GHI
- JKL
```

When I select GHI will save id=3

When I select JKL will save id=4

The problem is It works only when I choose GHI and JKL but when I choose ABC or DEF is not saving id=1 or id=2.

Maybe I need to write a condition.

Here is the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/HgqNf/59/

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: Why don't you use jquery is simple to make this kind of stuff using that framework library. What you need to do is listen when the select changes and grab the value and Validate that a selection must be made when the selection is active and disable it when not. That way you will prevent the issue that you are saying. You should also look up for nested select boxes

Comment: I recommend using console.log() to see if the value is getting empty.

Comment: I see also that you second select box has no name or id to identify itself

Comment: `var value= document.getElementById("select1");` will **Never** be equal to `A`

Comment: That's because you are not defining a id for the second select in order it do what you want it to do

Comment: @Carlitos Morales yo havn't used name property in second select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

### HTMl

```
<form action="#" class="new_invoice" id="new_client_form" method="post">

    <select id="select1">
        <option value="">PLEASE SELECT AN OPTION</option>
        <option value="1">ABC</option>
        <option value="2">DEF</option>
        <option value="A">OTHER</option>
    </select>

    <select id="info1" style="display: none;">
        <option value="3">GHI</option>
        <option value="4">JKL</option>
    </select>

    <input id="invoice_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
var select2 = document.getElementById("info1");

select1.onchange = function () {
    if (select1.value == "A") {
        select2.style.display = "inline";
        select1.removeAttribute('name');
        select2.setAttribute('name', "select1");
    }
    else {
        select2.style.display = "none";
        select2.removeAttribute('name');
        select1.setAttribute('name', "select1");
    }
};
//this section used to serialize the form data and display it in alert box.
//don't use this in your project it is used for demo.
$("#new_client_form").on("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).serialize());
});
```

Here is the updated **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HgqNf/85/)**

Comment: So you don't want select1 value, if select2 is available right?

Comment: @CarlitosMorales I've used jQuery for serializing the form data nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55742/discussion-between-super-and-carlitos-morales).

Comment: You are really SUPERMAN =)

Answer (score 1):

You may possibly try this example:

**html**

```
<form onsubmit="return showId()" action="#">
    <select onchange="mainId(this.value)" id="main">
        <option value="1">ABC</option>
        <option value="2">DEF</option>
        <option value="">OTHER</option>
    </select>
    <select id="sub">
        <option value="3">GHI</option>
        <option value="4">JKL</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**script**

```
var showId = function()
{
    console.log('showId');
    var id = document.getElementById('id');
    var v = document.getElementById('main').value;
    if('' == v)
    {
        v = document.getElementById('sub').value;
    }
    id.value = v;
    alert(id.value);
    return false;
};

var mainId = function(v)
{
    console.log('mainId: ' + v);
    var sub = document.getElementById("sub");
    sub.style.display = ('' === v ? 'inline-block' : 'none');
};
```

Comment: happy to help you, @Carlitos Morales